# Getting Thumbnail from RSS Feed and Display in Listview

Tags: php, jquery, xml, feed

i need some help with my RSS Feed Reader Script...
I want Thumbnails in my Listview taken from Rss Feeds Thumbnail

```
"content": [
      {
       "medium": "image",
       "url": "http://www......de/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/sgroth_web.jpg",
       "title": {
        "type": "html",
        "content": "sgroth_web"
       },
       "description": {
        "type": "html",
        "content": "contenthere 4."
       },
       "thumbnail": {
        "url": "http://www.sdddd.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/sgroth_web-150x150.jpg"
       }
```

have a look what i mean:
[Preview](http://media-owl.de/1test/#site.php?siteName=aktuelle_ausgabe)

First comes the Thumbnail and then the Title of the Rss Feed..
This Code is Jquery and PHP...

and here is my Code to Display RssFeeds in JS:

```
$(function(){


getOnlineFeed('http://salzstreuner.de/category/aktuelle_ausgabe/feed');
    });
/* functions */
var listEntries = function(json) {
  if (!json.responseData.feed.entries) return false;
  $('#widgetTitle').text(json.responseData.feed.title);
  var articleLength =json.responseData.feed.entries.length;
  articleLength = (articleLength > maxLength) ? maxLength : articleLength;
  for (var i = 1; i <= articleLength ; i++) {
    var entry = json.responseData.feed.entries[i-1];
    $('#link' + i).text(entry.title);
    $('#articleHeader' + i).text(entry.title);
    $('#openButton' + i).attr('href', entry.link);
    $('#articleContent' + i).append(entry.content);
 $('#articleImage').append('<img src="' + entry.thumbnail + '">');
  }
  $('#article1 .prevButton').remove();
  $('#article' + articleLength + ' .nextButton').remove();
  if (articleLength < maxLength) {
    for (i = articleLength + 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
      $('#list' + i).remove();
      $('#article' + i).remove();
    }
  }
};
var getOnlineFeed = function(url) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?callback=listEntries&hl=ja&output=json-in-script&q='
                      + encodeURIComponent(url)
                      + '&v=1.0&num=' + maxLength);
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
};
var getOfflineFeed = function(url) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('src', url);
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
};
```

Output looks like This:

```
for(var i=1; i<=maxLength; i++){
  document.write(
    '<li id="list' + i + '"><img src="#articleImage"/><a href="#article' + i + '" id="link' + i + '">&nbsp;</a></li>'
  );
```

I have Played with #articleImage but it doesn't work. I hope someone Outside can help me with this littleBig Problem...

THX
MAsterluke

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? What should it be doing, that it's not doing? I looked at the Preview and it looks fine to me (FF 3.6).

Comment: http://media-owl.de/mobile/  look at this.. the above Preview is my PHP Code, but i need Js to do the same thing

Comment: Ah, I can't figure it out. `entry.thumbnails` is empty, though it does exist in the `mediaGroups` if you `entry.toSource()`. You could try another script...or perhaps you can use the PHP version. This may apply: http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=436

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `url` of the `thumbnail`:

```
('#articleImage').append('<img src="' + entry.thumbnail.url + '">');
```